# Embed java applet from latest github commit

Tags: java, github

I would like to embed a Java app on my webpage but using the latest version of my code from GitHub, I don't want to have update webpage ever time i make a commit to GitHub, how would I go about doing this.

Comment: show us what you have so far and where your problems are

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this from GitHub directly, as it only *stores* code, it does not compile it.

Use some continuous integration service and have GitHub trigger a build each time you commit. One sample service I've used is [travis](https://travis-ci.org), but there are many others.

You'll also need to store the binaries somewhere. I assume the server that serves your page could be used for that.